# Tagging a friend to the wall post using graph API in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

I am using this code to post on my wall and at the same time I want to tag to my specefic friends but don't know how I am using Fbgrapgh API please help me.

[variables setObject:messageTextView.text forKey:@"message"];
[graphref doGraphPost:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/feed",self.friendID] withPostVars:variables];
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To tag someone you have to use FbDialogs. you cannot tag your friends in status update in any way other than FB dialogs.

to share status using FBDialog refer this sample code

```
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:nil handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {

    if(error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);

  } else {

        NSLog(@"Success!");

    }

}];
```

it is taken from here https://developers.facebook.com/ios/share-dialog/#statusupdate